# Best ffmpeg configuration for universal video codec compatabiltiy across browsers

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding, libx264

I intend to get a transcoding setting to support all browsers at the same time including, chrome, firefox and safari.

Currently I am using following, yet this does not provide a valid video with Safari :

`ffmpeg -i ${f} -y -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -preset faster videofile-new`

What would be the suggestion here for the configuration ?

Comment: the -f mp4 is redundant if the file extension is .mp4

Comment: Show the complete log.